# Is it safe, to modify the CoreData generated NSManagedObject properties from Int32 to Int?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When designing CoreData, we have to explicitly specific the bit of the used Integer

- Integer 16
- Integer 32
- Integer 64

[image]

If we pick Integer 32, the Core Data generated NSManagedObject class would be

```
extension NSPlainNote {
    @NSManaged public var colorIndex: Int32
    ...
}
```

However, throughout rest of the application code, we are operating based on `Int`. Hence, it is pretty troublesome and error prone, of having to perform casting between `Int32` and `Int`

I was wondering, **is it a safe act, to modify the XCode generated class to**

```
extension NSPlainNote {
    @NSManaged public var colorIndex: Int
    ...
}
```

Is there any potential pitfall we may fall into, if we choose to do so?

Comment: Yes, overflow if you don't have full control of the attribute in code. I would suggest either setting it to Int64 or add a computed property that takes and returns Int but safely converts it to Int32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not concerned with exceeding `Int32.max`, there are no pitfalls to this. Integer sizes are not used in the SQLite data store, so Core Data doesn't actually care what size you use. The only potential issue would be if you really don't want values that are too large for `Int32`, because `Int` would allow larger values. I usually use "Integer 64" for everything unless I have some reason to limit the acceptable values in code.